# refreshing returned data from $http promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, rest

I'm accessing json data from mongodb using restful api, I built angularjs factory as following:

```
angular.module('myApp').
factory('usersFactory', function($http, $q){
 var deffered = $q.defer();

return {
getUsers: function(){
return $http.get('/api/users/').then(function(result){ deffered.resolve(result);  return deffered.promise; });
},

getUser: function(nickname){
return $http.get('/api/users/'+nickname).then(function(result){ deffered.resolve(result);  return deffered.promise; });
}
};
}).
controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, usersFactory){
  var promise = usersFactory.getUsers();
  promise.then(function(response){
        //success handler
        $scope.users= response.data;
      },
      function(response){
        //error handler
        $log.error(response);
      });
}).
controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, usersFactory){
  $scope.loadUser = function(){
    var promise = usersFactory.getUsers($scope.usersFld);
  promise.then(function(response){
        //success handler
        $scope.user= response.data;
      },
      function(response){
        //error handler
        $log.error(response);
      });
};

});
```

The problem the data displays for the first user when I change the user it doesn't display until I do a hard refresh (with F5), can anyone explain why is this happening? and does the data gets cached so I need to do a hard refresh to display the new ones?

Comment: How do you changing the data of users?

Comment: the user list is store i the database and I display users and user information according to the URL, if the url contains `/users` alone it will generate $http request and gets the data, if it contains `/users/john` the page will display john info. The problem I'm facing that when I get john info and click back and select another user the user page still displays john info until I do a hard refresh.

Comment: Okay, how are you managing your url transition? Are you using ui-router or something? How these two controllers are mapped?

Comment: i'm using ui-router, and this is not the idea, as I described everything is working fine except the returned data needs refreshing to be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot re-use the deferred.  You should see that the call to `loadUser()` is returned instantly since the promise has already been resolved and that `$scope.user` should be the result of your initial call to `getUsers()` instead since that is what it was resolved with.

You can Move your `var deferred = $q.defer();` into your `getUsers()` and `getUser()` functions and return the promise directly, or just return the result of `$http.get` and don't bother creating your own deferred.

```
getUsers: function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/users/').then(function(result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    }, function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return deferred.promise; // result will be what you call resolve() with
},

getUser: function(nickname){
    return $http.get('/api/users/'+nickname);
}
```

Comment: thanx the problem was with the deffered variable when I just set it to getUsers function it worked fine without refreshing the page, thanx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a watch event and then fire your ajax call from there. 
[Depending on the size of your dataset, you could get the userdata you need with the first call and then you would only do a single $http get.]

```
//my suggestion if the dataset is not to big
//$scope.Users = ajax call getting all user data
//var index = 'find index of user by ...'
//$scope.User = $scope.Users[index]     


controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, usersFactory){
    scope.$watch("usersFld", function (newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.loadUser = function(){
            var promise = usersFactory.getUsers($scope.usersFld);
            promise.then(function(response){
            //success handler
            $scope.user= response.data;
        },
        function(response){
        //error handler
        $log.error(response);
        });
      }; 
   });
```